# Motion of a bouncing sphere with a spring attached inside

Tags: classical-mechanics, spring, chaos-theory

[image: Sketch]

Imagine a sphere with inside a spring attached (between opposite sides). You let it fall from a certain height, after which it bounces from a flat surface. The sphere is rigid.

Will the following motion be chaotic or can we put a nice function upon its subsequent motion? For simplicity, we’ll let friction out of the game.

Comment: What do **you** think?  What effort have you made to work through this problem?

Comment: Well, if we assume that the sphere reaches the surface without tension in the sphere, then upon impact the spring picks up kinetic energy, which causes the sphere to bounce less high than the height from where it fell. Of course the spring constant plays a role.

Comment: Can you construct the equation of motion?

Comment: It has to be a non-linear differential equation because of the coupling of the motion of the spring (let´s assume it´s in vertical position) and the bouncing motion of the sphere. My comments cannot be too long because every 5 minutes or so my computer crashes and then restarts again. I have to get into the problem a bit deeper. I never liked the connection between math and physics.

Comment: Which doesn´t mean I don´t like mathematics. On the contrary. But back to the problem. What are the important variables? Of course the spring constant. The mass of the sphere, the diameter of the sphere (or is there scale independency?), and the height from which the sphere falls. But what next?

Comment: What is the smallest number of co-ordinates you need to describe the motion?

Comment: Two. One for the motion of the spring and one for the motion of the sphere (if I make the assumption its linear motion is one-dimensional). But you can ask yourself if the rotation of the sphere also plays a role, which I don´t think so (in which case the number would be five).

Comment: If the sphere is "rigid" then I assume it cannot be deformed? If it cannot be deformed, then the spring cannot absorb any force if both the top and bottom of the spring are attached to the inside bottom and inside top of the sphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the spring’s mass is distributed homogeneously across the spring.

In this case, you have to use a partial differential equation (PDE) to perfectly describe the spring, whose solution would for example be a function which describes how each infinitesimal segment of the spring is shifted from its resting position (when no external forces and gravity are applied). Under benign boundary conditions the solution to these PDE would be longitudinal waves propagating on the spring.

However, the boundary conditions of the PDE for this problem are described by the sphere’s motion but also feed back into the sphere’s motion: The spring perceives a “kick” (starting a new wave) whenever the sphere bounces, and the sphere’s motion is affected by waves reaching the end of the spring. Thus I strongly doubt that there is a nice analytic solution to this problem – except perhaps in some benign cases, such as when the spring’s natural frequency matches the frequency of the bouncing.

As for chaoticity, you have infinitely many degrees of freedom (the position and momentum of the sphere as well as that of every point in the spring). You also have at least one clear non-linear component introduced by the sphere’s bouncing off the surface (you can have more if the spring is non-linear or due to the PDE’s boundary conditions). So, all the necessary ingredients for chaos are present.

I thus would expect chaos for at least some parameter choices. While I cannot prove this system without actually simulating it, I can appeal to intuition: If the parameters of the system are such, that the reflection of a spring wave at the spring’s end can be seen as a singular event, it can make a considerable difference whether this reflection happens before or after the sphere bouncing. Here a tiny difference in the state can eventually considerably affect the dynamics and thus you have the butterfly effect. Moreover the system bears a certain resemblance to the kicked oscillator, which exhibits chaos and is arguably less complicated.

Comment: So the time between subsequent boucings is not periodic, like a water droplet falling from a leaking tap?

Comment: What about the collection of all different spheres with different springs, which fall from different heights?

Comment: *So the time between subsequent boucings is not periodic, like a water droplet falling from a leaking tap?* – That’s what I argue at least for some parameter configurations. But as I said, I would have to simulate this to be sure. Also, there are almost certainly some parameter configurations that exhibit periodicity. — *What about the collection of all different spheres with different springs, which fall from different heights?* – That would be independent systems unless I am misunderstanding your setup.

Comment: But do they form some kind of "butterfly figure""?

Comment: @descheleschilder: I fail to follow you. What should form such a figure? And what does this have to do with what?

Answer (score 0):

I think with every bounce some energy is transferred to the spring. This means that after every bounce the height of the (undeformable) sphere is equal or less than the height it fell from. The sequence of successive heights is highly dependent on the height, the masses and the spring constant, and therefore chaotic (no friction involved).

Comment: This can't be right, for the same reason that you can't pull yourself up by your own bootstraps. Once your system has bounced off the ground with velocity $v$, its CM should reach height $v^2/2g$ no matter what the internal motion is.

Comment: I mean, if you don't believe this, imagine it happening in reverse. Then you have a ball that bounces up to a height higher than the height you dropped it from, which is clearly impossible.

Comment: @knzhou: You ignore the possibility of storing kinetic energy in the deformation of the spring or internal motions of the spring. If neither is the case for the initial condition, the assumption on the height in this answer are correct. They do not necessarily imply chaos though. The same applies to a quasiperiodic motion, whose initial condition is such that both periodic components are at their maximum.

Comment: @knzhou Imagine it happening in reverse. Then the kinetic energy of the spring is given back to the sphere, so the sphere is getting higher.